# how to catch SQL error in migration in AdonisJS

Tags: sql, bash, migration, adonis.js

I just started using adonisJS and I’ve been searching about this question for a while but had no luck finding answers. I’m wondering if I can get any help here.

The command `adonis migrate:refresh` always returns a code 0 no matter whether it encounters an SQL error or not. I wonder if there’s a way to catch this error other than testing if there’s the word ‘Error’ in the output?

Here’s some background information:
I have a script to run a database `migrate:refresh` and `seeding` together on my server automatically. But sometimes, if someone manually modified my database schema(e.g. deleted a table), the `migration:refresh` will encounter SQL error and rollback all the operations. But since I couldn’t detect this (migration:refresh exited with code 0), the seeding part of my script will still run, which leads to duplicated seeding in my database.

I have a sample bash script to detect the SQL failure but I don’t think it is a good solution. I want to know if there's any good way to detect the SQL error during migration?

Here's my sample script

```sh
#/usr/bin/env bash

adonis migration:refresh | grep 'Error'

if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then 
    echo "Success, can start seeding"
else
    echo "Failed, do not run seeding"
fi
```

I’ve also set up a [repo](https://github.com/AaronHongyangLiu/adonis-api-app) for reproducing the migration SQL error by modifying one of the migration files in the sample boilerplate. To use it, simple clone it, rename the ".env.example" file to ".env" and run the followings:

```
npm install
adonis migration:run
adonis migration:refresh
```

---

TL;DR: Any good way to detect the SQL error when using command `adonis migration:refresh` in a script other than “grep” the word “Error” in the command output?